# How can I create core data records from a data file for UI Testing?

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode-ui-testing

I’m trying to create some complex UI Tests, which are dependent on data.

My app uses CoreData.

I’m assuming I’ll have to pass in some launch arguments and run some code to add this data.

I know that I could create some lines of code to create all the entities I need and the values for fields etc.

However I’d rather keep this data outside of my app and have some way to load my data via some kind of data file. I’m thinking json.

But obviously I’m going to need some mechanism to transform json into core data records.

Or maybe I’m missing some different approach which would be easier?

Comment: Json is of course a good choice but you could also consider a csv file depending on how complicated your data model is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082117/coredata-codable-not-saving